# What is the commonly used abbrevation for Difference-in-Differences in writing?

Tags: terminology, difference-in-difference, reporting, academia

I am trying to repeat the word "Difference-in-Differences" in my paper many times. I am using "DiD" instead (but I am not sure whether it is true or not). I am looking for any other way to write "Difference-in-Differences" in short version in an academic paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest picking one and using it consistently throughout your paper. Common abbreviations include DD, DiD, and Diff-in-Diff.

As a technique, difference-in-differences is actually a *double difference* estimator, though this description is rarely used in academic papers. It’s only when authors also estimate difference-in-difference-in-differences, then the term *triple difference* estimator seems to be preferred.

I derive my opinion from a survey of the literature in economics, political science, and criminology, but other abbreviations may be preferred in other disciplines. If I had to choose, I would go with either DD or DiD, though I tilt a bit more toward the latter.